# How to modify add to wishlist success message in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, wishlist, messages

I have `wishlist text` coming twice when adding a product to wish list from cart (url : `my_project/checkout/cart/`) , **but its not there when adding from single product view . how to remove that ?**

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wishlist word has been show twice because of you have creating a `wishlist` group.Name is `wishlist`..

### Code is manipulate from:

```
  $session->addSuccess(
            Mage::helper('wishlist')->__("%s has been moved to wishlist %s", $productName, $wishlistName)
        );
```

Comment: can you specify where the file location is

Comment: thanks i modifed by removing %s in succes message in  Project\app\code\core\Mage\Wishlist\controllers\IndexController.php in fromCart action

Comment: yes, this the location

Comment: @AmitBera perfect, Solved my issue

Answer (score 3):

Actually the right way to do this is to simply change the wording in the translate.csv file of your theme. You'll find it here:
**/app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/locale/en_US/translate.csv**

Just enter a new line in that file that looks like this:

```
"%s has been moved to wishlist %s","%s has been moved to your wishlist"
```

This way you don't have to modify or override any core files. You're upgrade-proof!

Comment: Always use the translation files to modify displayed text. Saves a lot of grief down the road. You might look up the original template file for the display string if it contains parameters like this, but that should be the only reason for dealing with the file.